# Does Jhipster support sticky sessions with docker stack or HAproxy?

Tags: spring-security, jhipster, sticky-session

Running a sample jhipster app (found at : https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3-samples/tree/master/fullstack) , when I deployed it to a **docker swarm** (swarm mode) with **docker stack**, it worked fine and I could log-in

But when I started "scaling" the web app, I found out the session was lost whenever my request would hit another container than the first one.

Actually, I even saw in the logs :

```
    worker2    | org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.CookieTheftException: Invalid remember-me token (Series/token) mismatch. Implies previous cookie theft attack.
    worker2    |         at org.terracotta.demo.security.CustomPersistentRememberMeServices.getPersistentToken(CustomPersistentRememberMeServices.java:173)
    worker2    |         at org.terracotta.demo.security.CustomPersistentRememberMeServices.processAutoLoginCookie(CustomPersistentRememberMeServices.java:83)
    worker2    |         at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.AbstractRememberMeServices.autoLogin(AbstractRememberMeServices.java:130)
```

while I was trying to logging in again...
Is there something I need to setup to have the load balancer treat the session as unique ?

Comment: I tried out : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11944824/24069 and it worked pretty well (commenting out the code that threw the exception). I initially thought it was configurable from Spring / JHipster